Why beg for mercy in the middle of the praise litany of the first benediction before Sh'ma?
The first portion of the first benediction recited before the morning Sh'ma praises God for having created astronomical objects. Versions vary among the different communities, and on the sabbath from weekdays, but one version is as follows; others are similar.

All will thank and praise you, and say there no one holy like God. All will exalt you forever, creator of everything. The god who opens the eastern gates every day, cleaving the windows of the sky, bringing the sun from its place and the moon from its settlement, and illuminating the entire world and its inhabitants, whom he had created with mercy. Who illuminates the world and its inhabitants with mercy, and who, in his goodness, renews daily and constantly the work of creation. The king, who alone is exalted from always, who is praised and exalted since forever. The god of the world, in your mercy, have mercy upon us, our strength master, our refuge rock, our salvation shield, our refuge. There is none like you and none but you, nothing without you, and who compares to you? There's none like you, God, our god, in this world; none but you, king, in the next; nothing without you, our savior, in the days of the messiah; and none to compare to you at the revivification of the dead. God, master of all creation, blessed by the mouth of all souls. His strength and goodness fill the world; knowledge and understanding surround his splendor. He is exalted over the chaya angels, honorably splendid over the merkava. Righteousness and straightness are before his throne; kindness and mercy fill his presence. Good are the illuminations that our god made; he formed them with knowledge, understanding, and intelligence; he put strength in them that they may control earth; they're full of glow, and give off glow; their glow is nice all over the world; they are happy when they rise and when they set, doing their creator's will with reverence.…

What is the boldfaced sentence doing there?  ("The god of the world, in your mercy, have mercy upon us, our strength master, our refuge rock, our salvation shield, our refuge.")  Why are we suddenly begging for mercy in the middle of a litany of praises?

Worth noting that in R Saadia Gaon's siddur, a similar phrase is only introduced into this blessing when it is recited with a minyan, and looks to me like it may be functioning as part of the introduction to the kedusha verses inserted into the blessing.

רחם עלינו is not request for mercy. It is a prase of G-d who is the source of mercy upon us, just like אדון עוזינו - master of our strength.

https://www.sefaria.org/Derekh_Mitzvotekha%2C_Discourses.14.6?vhe=Kehot_Publication_Society&lang=he&with=all&lang2=he

Daniel Goldschmidt identifies several sentences like this in various brachos and suggests that they were added by people davening in an era before the tefilla reached as fixed a form as it has today.  They eventually became crystallized as part of the tefillah.
For several other additions like this (though not this one), he points out a machlokes whether or not to say it.  Some were eventually accepted and some were not.
